# IMAP and command APPEND and its parameters and RFC 2060

Tags: php, email, imap, rfc

Can you help me to understand what is the last parameter in example of APPEND command in RFC 2060. There is example C: A003 APPEND saved-messages (\Seen) {310} and what mean the {310}

Thank M.

Answer (score 2):

310 is the number of bytes in the message literal that you're appending

Comment: This parameter can be omitted? Becouse in the RFC is:  Arguments:     mailbox name
               OPTIONAL flag parenthesized list
               OPTIONAL date/time string
               message literal

Comment: I *think* that the {301} counts as the message literal, not either of the two optional flags you mentioned as it's doesn't relate to flags or date/time

Comment: Yes, {301} is part of the definition of the "literal". From rfc 3501: `literal         = "{" number "}" CRLF *CHAR8
                    ; Number represents the number of CHAR8s`